# include optional css file in xhtml?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, icefaces, jsf-1.2, icefaces-1.8

I have an xhtml page where I do include some css files like:

```
<link
    href="resources/css/graCommon.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<link
    href="resources/css/txMart.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"/>
```

I do need to include the second CSS file based on some conditions  (for instance, using a bean property etc). So I need some sort of jsf/icefaces tag having an attribute like render or visible...

Are you aware of something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work for build time

```
<c:if test="#{yourExpression}">
    <link
    href="resources/css/txMart.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"/>
</c:if>
```

Will include your tag in the facelet depending on your expression, you will need to include the "c" namespace

or

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{yourExpression}">
    <link
    href="resources/css/txMart.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

See https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat for the differences in each approach